# LightGBMError (train_data->num_features()) > (0)

Tags: python, lightgbm

I am getting the error

> [LightGBM] [Fatal] Check failed: (train_data->num_features()) > (0)

for my dataset X with shape (40,7). I am trying to run a gradient boosting for custom loss function

Would be grateful for any solution or hints.

The error comes up on the line

```
gbm.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
    eval_metric=custom_asymmetric_valid,
    verbose=False,
)
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import lightgbm
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv("Data_Train.csv")
X, y = train.iloc[:, 1:-1], train.iloc[:, -1] 

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
print(np.shape(X_train),np.shape(X_valid))


test = pd.read_csv("Data_Test.csv")
X_test, y_test = test.iloc[:, 1:-1], test.iloc[:, -1] 

# Defining custom loss function

def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    grad = np.where(residual<0, -2*10.0*residual, -2*residual)
    hess = np.where(residual<0, 2*10.0, 2.0)
    return grad, hess

def custom_asymmetric_valid(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    loss = np.where(residual < 0, (residual**2)*10.0, residual**2) 
    return "custom_asymmetric_eval", np.mean(loss), False

# default lightgbm model with sklearn api
gbm = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(random_state=33) 

# updating objective function to custom
# default is "regression"
# also adding metrics to check different scores
gbm.set_params(**{'objective': custom_asymmetric_train}, metrics = ["mse", 'mae'])

# fitting model 
gbm.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
    eval_metric=custom_asymmetric_valid,
    verbose=False,
)

y_pred = gbm.predict(X_valid)


# create dataset for lightgbm

lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train, free_raw_data=False)
lgb_eval = lgb.Dataset(X_valid, y_valid, reference=lgb_train, free_raw_data=False)


params = {
    'objective': 'regression',
    'verbose': 0
}

gbm = lgb.train(params,
                lgb_train,
                num_boost_round=10,
                init_model=gbm,
                fobj=custom_asymmetric_train,
                feval=custom_asymmetric_valid,
                valid_sets=lgb_eval)
                
y_pred = gbm.predict(X_valid)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original example isn't fully reproducible (since the content of `"Data_Train.csv"` isn't shared), but I can reliably reproduce the error message you mentioned with the following code, using LightGBM 3.1.1 (installed with `pip install lightgbm`).

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(708)

def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    grad = np.where(residual<0, -2*10.0*residual, -2*residual)
    hess = np.where(residual<0, 2*10.0, 2.0)
    return grad, hess

# create a training dataset of shape (40, 7)
X = pd.DataFrame({
    f"feat_{i}": np.random.random((40,))
    for i in range(7)
})
y = np.random.random((40,))

gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor()
gbm.set_params(**{'objective': custom_asymmetric_train}, metrics = ["mse", 'mae'])
gbm.fit(X, y)
```

> LightGBMError: Check failed: (train_data->num_features()) > (0)

LightGBM has some parameters that are used to prevent overfitting. Two are relevant in this case:

- [`min_data_in_leaf`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#min_data_in_leaf) (default=20)
- [`min_sum_hessian_in_leaf`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#min_sum_hessian_in_leaf) (default=0.001)

By default, during construction of the `Dataset` object, LightGBM filters out features that are impossible to split based on these conditions (see [`feature_pre_filter`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#feature_pre_filter).

LightGBM's parameter default values are intended to offer good performance on moderate-sized datasets. A dataset of shape `(40, 7)` is very small, which increases the risk that all features will be unsplittable.

To fit on such a small dataset, you can override the defaults and set them to 0 or smaller values. The code below trains successfully with no error.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(708)

def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    grad = np.where(residual<0, -2*10.0*residual, -2*residual)
    hess = np.where(residual<0, 2*10.0, 2.0)
    return grad, hess

# create a training dataset of shape (40, 7)
X = pd.DataFrame({
    f"feat_{i}": np.random.random((40,))
    for i in range(7)
})
y = np.random.random((40,))

gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    min_sum_in_hessian=0,
    min_data_in_leaf=0
)
gbm.set_params(**{'objective': custom_asymmetric_train}, metrics = ["mse", 'mae'])
gbm.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, I've set `min_data_in_leaf` to one value smaller than default one to make my code works.